# Edit resource_path by a dynamic attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

**Program (object)**

```
    #<Program id: 1, country: "UK", title: "Bee Movie", subtitle: "Born to bee wild.", 
description: "Barry B. Benson, a bee who has just graduated from ...", official_rating: 6.1,
 rating: 6.1, ptype: "movie", year: "2007", imdb: "0389790", tmdb: "5559", tvdb: nil, wiki: 
"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee_Movie", poster: "/QhbOzpYfBOwrRiuTu9otPk919R.jpg", backdrop:
 "/eKXTOIqSFrfN8WTTxrzHMBNiUpB.jpg", trailer: "FFGaS6MDknY", popularity: 4.6948, tags: nil, 
created_at: "2013-12-29 21:47:45", updated_at: "2013-12-29 21:48:09">
```

**Program(Model)**

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessor :subdomain

 def subdomain
     'something elaborated'
  end
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
 scope ":subdomain" do
     resources :programs
   end
```

Now, If I call this

```
p = Program.first
program_path(p)
```

I get

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:locale=>:en, :action=>"show", :controller=>"programs", :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:subdomain, :id]
```

I have set attr_accessor in my Model. What else is missing?

My url should be: `http://example.com/uk/programs/1-bee-movie`

Btw, I've called ':subdomain' for old reasons. Because before it was uk.example.com, but now, for seo, should be, example.com/uk

Answer (score 0):

the routes.rb

```
scope "/(:subdomain)" do
    resources :programs
end
```

the view file

```
program_path(program, :subdomain => 'uk')
```

Comment: I cannot remove :subdomain because I want that every link has its own /uk/

Comment: I have to edit in thousands of parts. I was looking for something that edit the resourse from routes.rb. This is because "subdomain" is an attribute of Program

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

using :subdomain was in conflict with 'subdomain' of Rails

```
url program_url(p, :country_prefix => 'uk')
```